# Is there any special reason to use "std-pair" instead of "stdpair"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today I want to ask question about std::pair, but cannot find [stdpair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdpair), but find [std-pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/std-pair).

But I find there are similar tags like "stdvector","stdmap","stdstring","std vector"...

Is there any special reason to use "std-pair" instead of "stdpair"? If not, should "std-pair" be replaced by "stdpair"?

Comment: Well, the whole tag is arguable. There's no detailed tag-wiki, and the short description is plain wrong. There's no thing like the Standard Template Library (besides of some special implementations), it's called the c++ standard library.

Comment: This started out with questioners tagging their questions with [c++] [pair].  Then on May 2nd 2012, an SO user probably assumed that C++ programmers could be confused about "pair" might mean and mass-edited all these questions to [std-pair] instead.  Retagging them yet again is pointless, the post editor doesn't need that kind of help.  Questioners simply continue to use "pair" and std-pair pops up in the list.

Comment: I'd say tagging a question `pair` is about as useful as tagging it `int`. I can see a tag `piecewise_construct` though. Point being: it's so broad, it's useless. Without looking at the questions in case, I suspect I'd just want to remove the tags